# JQuery LT Selector Working but GT Is Not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I am working on a star rating option.  I have a span containing a hidden input and five images.  When one of the image is hovered over, that image and every sibling image to the left is set to the a highlighted version of the image and every sibling to the right is dimmed.

#### The HTML

```
<span>
 <input type="hidden" value="1" class="starCount">
 <img src="star-on.jpg" alt="Rating:1 Star" class="rating"><!--
 --><img src="star-off.jpg" alt="Rating:2 Stars" class="rating"><!--
 --><img src="star-off.jpg" alt="Rating:3 Stars" class="rating"><!--
 --><img src="star-off.jpg" alt="Rating:4 Stars" class="rating"><!--
 --><img src="star-off.jpg" alt="Rating:5 Stars" class="rating">
</span>
```

#### The JQuery

```
click: (function(){
  // Set the hidden input value to which rating you clicked
  $(this).siblings(".starCount:eq(0)").val($(this).index());
}),
mouseover: (function(){
  // Highlight the star being hovered + all stars to the left
  $(this).attr("src","star-on.jpg");
  $(this).prevAll(".rating").attr("src","star-on.jpg");
  $(this).nextAll(".rating").attr("src","star-off.jpg");
}),
mouseout:(function(){
  // Reset highlighted stars to the value of the hidden input

  // Get the position of the hovered element
  var stars = parseInt($(this).siblings(".starCount:eq(0)").val());

  if($(this).index() != stars){
    // Highlight this element and everything to it's left
    $(this).siblings(".rating:lt("+(stars-1)+")").attr("src","star-on.jpg");

    // Dim everything to the right
    /* -- Note this line: It works, but is where my question derives from -- */
    $(this).siblings(".rating:eq("+(stars-1)+")").nextAll().attr("src","star-off.jpg");
  }
})
```

My problem is how I had to accomplish the "dimming" portion.  This works for [this element] + previous siblings:

```
$(this).siblings(".rating:lt("+(stars-1)+")").attr("src","star-on.jpg");
```

**Why does this not work properly for everything after:**

```
$(this).siblings(".rating:gt("+(stars-1)+")").attr("src","star-off.jpg");
```

---

I just noticed that I didn't explain *what* is not working when using the GT selector.  Here's how I can reproduce my issue.
See http://jsfiddle.net/SNmcB/1/:

- Click the third star.
- Mouse over star 1 and back out; it resets back to 3 selected.
- Click the first star.
- Mouse over star 4 or 5 and back out;  the star you were hovered over remains highlighted.
- If I use the nextAll() method instead of GT, this behavior doesn't happen.

Comment: Can you please provide the html snippet that is used to render stars?

Comment: Added JSFiddle + a better explanation of my problem.  I didn't realize how much I was making you all guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first star's siblings are: 2 3 4 5

There is no gt() selector that can select this.

The second star's siblings are: 1 3 4 5
The gt parameter needs to be 0.

Star #3

Siblings: 1 2 4 5

index needed: 1

Star #4

Siblings: 1 2 3 5

index needed: 2

Star #5

Siblings: 1 2 3 4

index needed: 3

So the following should work:

```
if (stars === 1) {
    $(this).nextAll().attr("src","star-off.jpg");
} else {
    $(this).siblings(".rating:gt("+(stars - 2)+")").attr("src","star-off.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Very, very close.  Although your solution has the same error as mine, you made me find what the problem was.  `There is no gt() selector that can select this`:  Everything was setting to normal except the element that fired mouseout; it skipped itself because it is not in its collection of siblings but nextAll doesn't care about the collection; just the selected element.